# Lower ingest rate while using timesceledb for storing OSM data

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgis, openstreetmap, timescaledb

I have a task for my master thesis to prove that combination of timescale and postgis will improve PostgreSQL database performance for OSM data. I have prepared dataset with Europe OSM data (CSV file with 100M rows). 
When I start COPY that data in classic postgresql database, ingest rate is about 200k rows/second. When I COPY it inside timescale hypertable, ingest rate is lower then 100k rows/second. 
That result is not expected and my question is why it is happening? Do I need to set something? Maybe the problem is inhomogenity of osm timestamp varying from 2006 to 2019.

When I'm saving it in classic postgresql table:

```
   osm_timestamp    |                        way                         
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 2019-08-20 02:22:35 | 0101000020110F0000F0076BFEFFB162C14485197AF1B65341
 2019-08-05 15:46:38 | 0101000020110F00002BFC9A016E864AC17DB392F223375241
 2019-08-05 15:46:38 | 0101000020110F0000142668FD5A804AC14841650D62375241
 2014-04-22 19:36:43 | 0101000020110F0000A265A7382E7F4AC113BDE36F99375241
 2014-04-22 19:36:43 | 0101000020110F0000C91A02369D7E4AC1D7D24B7197375241
 2018-04-21 21:08:35 | 0101000020110F00003FCDEEF0747E4AC151E880038E375241
 2014-04-22 19:36:43 | 0101000020110F0000C3186511957E4AC19620025B92375241
 2017-12-10 17:43:50 | 0101000020110F0000B24BD8C58E7E4AC153B6CA5192375241
 2014-04-22 19:36:43 | 0101000020110F000014D08064937E4AC1C131DECE95375241
 2017-08-25 12:30:33 | 0101000020110F0000249BF33F977E4AC14AA0211597375241
 2014-04-22 19:36:43 | 0101000020110F0000EC629803907E4AC1DAC3FF3098375241
 2018-04-21 21:08:36 | 0101000020110F000043C2E8A5787E4AC18A7F52A18F375241
```

When I'm saving it in timescaledb table:

```
   osm_timestamp    |                        way                         
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 2019-08-20 02:22:35 | 0101000020110F0000F0076BFEFFB162C14485197AF1B65341
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F0000BA461AE38D7548C159769C60C3C75141
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F0000D8062171F57148C1081AC67C7BC65141
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F00000A3CD250F37148C13CB433AB7AC65141
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F0000E6C794D0F27148C1E4B157257CC65141
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F0000EB32A406717048C1D6F39FB772C65141
 2019-08-19 16:32:34 | 0101000020110F000066CAFEFFEE6048C18DD0C86240C15141
 2019-08-19 16:32:34 | 0101000020110F000058C74E3ADA6048C1244D22AC63C15141
 2019-08-19 16:32:34 | 0101000020110F00004ABED3D8C36048C14FEF45345FC15141
 2019-08-19 10:45:35 | 0101000020110F00005FBA75B7DE5E48C1FB21EF296DC15141
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F00000DF0FD868B7948C1EEA03CEE28C95141
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F000092EF4F0EE87548C1F7598342B4CB5141
 2019-08-19 19:25:36 | 0101000020110F0000B75DC2F2E67548C1C06DA855B4CB5141
 2019-08-20 18:41:46 | 0101000020110F0000E674D391CC5148C168E4DE3147C25141
 2019-08-20 18:02:29 | 0101000020110F0000FCE227F30C5148C1164B566039C25141
 2019-08-20 18:41:46 | 0101000020110F00007FA03258515148C1C88FDDB08AC25141
 2019-08-20 18:41:46 | 0101000020110F000094A2CFC1165148C15EA45CCAAAC25141
 2019-08-20 18:41:46 | 0101000020110F00004720D019315148C17DEEAD09B3C25141
```

Performance while saving in classic postgresql:

```
Stipe@Mile:~/go/bin$ ./timescaledb-parallel-copy --connection "host=localhost user=postgres sslmode=disable password=postgresifra54" --db-name timescale2 --table timescale2 --batch-size 10000 --truncate --log-batches --file /home/Stipe/DISKC/europe-point.csv | tee /home/Stipe/DISKC/postgis.txt
[BATCH] took 43.292909ms, batch size 10000, row rate 230984.709297/sec
[BATCH] took 35.496966ms, batch size 10000, row rate 281714.217491/sec
[BATCH] took 37.104837ms, batch size 10000, row rate 269506.641412/sec
[BATCH] took 36.998932ms, batch size 10000, row rate 270278.071810/sec
[BATCH] took 39.105424ms, batch size 10000, row rate 255719.002049/sec
[BATCH] took 38.659405ms, batch size 10000, row rate 258669.268190/sec
[BATCH] took 35.184652ms, batch size 10000, row rate 284214.833218/sec
[BATCH] took 40.266376ms, batch size 10000, row rate 248346.163558/sec
[BATCH] took 36.179696ms, batch size 10000, row rate 276398.121200/sec
```

Performance while saving in timescale hypertable:

```
Stipe@Mile:~/go/bin$ ./timescaledb-parallel-copy --connection "host=localhost user=postgres sslmode=disable password=postgresifra54" --db-name timescale --table timescale2 --batch-size 10000 --truncate --log-batches --file /home/Stipe/DISKC/europe-point.csv | tee /home/Stipe/DISKC/postgis.txt
[BATCH] took 6.979696947s, batch size 10000, row rate 1432.726962/sec
[BATCH] took 1.439723348s, batch size 10000, row rate 6945.778864/sec
[BATCH] took 1.27673852s, batch size 10000, row rate 7832.457346/sec
[BATCH] took 619.745584ms, batch size 10000, row rate 16135.653497/sec
[BATCH] took 378.107768ms, batch size 10000, row rate 26447.486263/sec
[BATCH] took 350.852359ms, batch size 10000, row rate 28502.017283/sec
[BATCH] took 194.37932ms, batch size 10000, row rate 51445.801951/sec
[BATCH] took 269.47735ms, batch size 10000, row rate 37108.870189/sec
[BATCH] took 206.672165ms, batch size 10000, row rate 48385.809478/sec
[BATCH] took 232.124194ms, batch size 10000, row rate 43080.386528/sec
[BATCH] took 169.58852ms, batch size 10000, row rate 58966.255499/sec
[BATCH] took 350.809657ms, batch size 10000, row rate 28505.486666/sec
[BATCH] took 117.911529ms, batch size 10000, row rate 84809.348881/sec
[BATCH] took 172.228338ms, batch size 10000, row rate 58062.454275/sec
[BATCH] took 121.701297ms, batch size 10000, row rate 82168.392996/sec
[BATCH] took 173.654201ms, batch size 10000, row rate 57585.707356/sec
[BATCH] took 154.958872ms, batch size 10000, row rate 64533.252410/sec
[BATCH] took 111.999767ms, batch size 10000, row rate 89285.900032/sec
[BATCH] took 176.024805ms, batch size 10000, row rate 56810.175134/sec
[BATCH] took 143.048944ms, batch size 10000, row rate 69906.143453/sec
```

Comment: 1. How is your hypertable partitioned, what is your chunk interval? 2. How much working memory do you have? 3. Did you use timescaledb-tune? 4. Is the PostgreSQL insert rate consistent for the complete data? TimescaleDB works best when the data comes in an ordered fashion, and the most recent chunk can fit into your working memory (chunk size ~25% RAM). Also it may be beneficial to partition the hypertable not on the timestamp but on something else if your timestamps are chaotic and will continuously trash the db looking for different chunks

Comment: I have used timescaledb-tune. I'v tried with different chunks: from 1 day to 10 years, and there are some small improvements in ingestion rate with bigger chunk size . I heave also ordered the data by date. But after all ingestion rate of classic postgres is much much higher. I need to explain it somehow in my master thesis. And I hope that lower ingestion rate will be compensated with better performance during complex queries.

Comment: Is your code Open Source, can we somehow test this, to see why it behaves like this? It may be something in the data layout that timescale doesn't handle well

Comment: This is dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sb92pci7gcs0zn/EU-time-desc.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

see following link to improve our ingestion performance. Also, check your base postgresql configuration, specially memory configuration.

https://blog.timescale.com/blog/13-tips-to-improve-postgresql-insert-performance/